# Appointment alignment in sap.m.PlanningCalendarRow

Tags: javascript, css, sapui5

I am currently using a planning calendar to display assignments. The thing that bothers me is that the appointments don't get aligned properly. When I create an appointment from 9 AM to 5 PM. The 'one month' view shows the appointment aligned over two days.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QU0L.png)

Is there a way to align the appointments centrally over a day? I have tried the method `SetNonWorkingHours` of `sap.m.PlanningCalendarRow`. But it doesn't change anything visually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I extended the control and added extra properties that hold the actual time. I now use the original time properties to hold a fake time to align my appointment.